# Translated text about Royal Baby

Tags: translation

I try translate russian text about British Royal Baby.

I have a big text and many questions. I create one question If you don't mind!

> He have been born heir to the British throne
>
> Heir to the throne was born on 22 july at 4.24pm London time, weighing
>   8lbs 6oz (3.9kg). Prince William and Princess Kate are could not be
>   happier. The name baby will have been announced later.
>
> The announcement was made rather late - half of the 9 evening, that is
>   4 hours after birth. 14 hours have passed, From the moment when Kate
>   and William arrived at the hospital on Monday, about half past five
>   London time in the morning.  When Kate with accompaniment by a
>   midwifes were entering through a side entrance the hospital, birth
>   pangs has already begun if believe sounds of witnesses.
>
> As required by tradition and royal protocol, the first of the birth of
>   an heir notified Elizabeth II, Lord Mayor David Cameron and newborn's
>   grandfather called Prince Charles of Wales. Then, according to the
>   same protocol were sent telegrams to the Governor-General,
>   representing Queen Elizabeth led in all its 15 countries
>
> After that, the royal chancery issued a press release in which it was
>   given the details of this historic event. By long tradition, going to
>   the time when there was not only mobile, but generally no telephones,
>   an information message in a simple frame put on a special wooden stand
>   in front of the fence of Buckingham Palace. Also a member of the
>   palace, dressed in a suit herald, read this information twice a
>   thunderous voice.

Questions:

1) It is title I wanted to say in present perfect time, passive voice.

> He have been born heir to the British throne

2) `weighing 8lbs 6oz (3.9kg)` or `weighed 8lbs 6oz (3.9kg)`

3) `could not be happier` - Is it idiom normal for this context?

4) It is passive voice, future perfect tens. Am I right?

> The name baby will have been announced later.

5) I tried to say `grandfather called Prince Charles of Wales notified too.`

> and newborn's grandfather called Prince Charles of Wales

6) I'm not totally sure about this translation. About `sounds of witnesses` and construction that sentence.

> When Kate with accompaniment by a midwifes were entering through a
>   side entrance the hospital, birth pangs has already begun if believe
>   sounds of witnesses.

7) last paragraph I translated with help google translation and to my point, there's all true.

> After that, the royal chancery issued a press release in which it was
>   given the details of this historic event. By long tradition, going to
>   the time when there was not only mobile, but generally no telephones,
>   an information message in a simple frame put on a special wooden stand
>   in front of the fence of Buckingham Palace. Also a member of the
>   palace, dressed in a suit herald, read this information twice a
>   thunderous voice.

If you know this text in native text please give it to me.

p.s And remember I'm just learning

Comment: First of all, you got Kate's title wrong. She is not a princess. She is a Duchess, specifically *The Duchess of Cambridge*. If you are going to use her title, it is sufficient in most cases, just to use that without her name as well. See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine,_Duchess_of_Cambridge#Titles_and_styles

In you article it would be better just to write *Prince William and Kate*.

Comment: Regarding number 5. You don't need the word *called*. Charles IS the Prince of Wales. Normally, it is sufficient just to refer to him as *Prince Charles*. If you really want to use his name and title together, it would be better to write *Charles, Prince of Wales*. People just don't say or write "Prince Charles of Wales", as you have.

Comment: David Cameron is NOT "Lord Mayor" of anything. He is the British Prime Minister.

Comment: In (7): not sure what you mean by "royal chancery"; in any case, the statement was issued by [Buckingham Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_Palace), which is the Queen's official residence in London.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. We say "The heir to the British throne **has been** born" - 3d person singular
2. "weighing 8lbs 6oz (3.9kg)" is fine; I'd space it "8 lbs, 6 oz", but rules vary
3. "could not be happier" is excellent, but we say "Prince William and HRH Catherine <strike>are</strike> could not be happier" - only one tensed verb (*could*) per clause. And although the mother bears the style *Princess William*, she is referred to as *Her Royal Highness Catherine, Duchess of Cambridge*.
4. "The baby's name will be announced later" - you have the name of the tense right, but it is built without *have*, which is part of the *perfect* tenses
5. The baby's grandfather is "Charles, Prince of Wales" - and he's not just *called* that, he really **is** that!
6. Either "When Kate, accompanied by a midwife, **was** entering" OR "When Kate, with a midwife, was entering" - singular, because Kate-by-herself is the subject. OR you could say "When Kate AND a midwife **were** entering" - you need an *and* to join them and make the subject plural. "If believe sounds of witnesses" should probably be "if the accounts of witnesses may be believed" - but there are lots of ways of saying this.
7. "in which the details **were given**" ... "going **back** to a time when there was not only **no** mobile" (the *not* belongs to *only*, not to *mobile*) "but mostly no telephones" ... "information message" is not English idiom; what you want is probably "a notice" ... "**was** put" ... and "**in** a thunderous voice". (In fact, he was not a Palace official, but as translator you wouldn't know that.

I applaud your effort. When I was learning German over 50 years ago I tried to translate the American Declaration of Independence into German; the result was embarrassingly comical. This does you great credit. I suggest you work especially on verbs, which I am told are especially difficult for Russian speakers.

Comment: Kate is not a princess. You should edit that out of your answer.

Comment: @Tristan Of course she isn't, how stupid of me. (But if all goes well, she will presumably become one ...)

Comment: Stoney, maybe. It seems to be a common mistake.

Comment: @Tristan Hangover from Diana, I imagine.